# Jquery Select All From Child Table Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to select all of the members of a table that are below an accordion tab. I can select all members of the table but I can't just select the ones belonging to the specific tab. A requirement for this jquery function is that it has to work with me dynamically filling in the table later.

Here's some code I've been working on in a jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/brandondestroy/ve77f/26/
Thanks!

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //accordion
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  $('#accordion input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#chckHead').click(function () {
    if (this.checked == false) {
      $('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else {
      $('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
    }
  }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><input type="checkbox" id ="chckHead"/> Suite 1</h3>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width=10%>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
        </td>
        <td width=90%>Test Case 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=10%>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
        </td>
        <td width=90%>Test Case 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <h3><input type="checkbox" id ="chckHead"/> Suite 2</h3>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width=10%>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
        </td>
        <td width=90%>Test Case 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=10%>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
        </td>
        <td width=90%>Test Case 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution; but, this works:

1. Change chckHead to a class. [**class ="chckHead"**]
2. Add an attribute called 'tab' and give each chckHead checkbox a unique value. [**tab='SuiteX'**]
3. Give the tables matching ids so they can be selected. [**table id='SuiteX'**]

   ```
   <div id="accordion">
    <h3><input type="checkbox" class ="chckHead" tab='Suite1'/> Suite 1</h3>

   <div>
       <table id='Suite1'>
           <tr>
               <td width=10%>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
               </td>
               <td width=90%>Test Case 1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td width=10%>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
               </td>
               <td width=90%>Test Case 2</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>

    <h3><input type="checkbox" class ="chckHead" tab='Suite2'/> Suite 2</h3>
   <div>
       <table id='Suite2'>
           <tr>
               <td width=10%>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
               </td>
               <td width=90%>Test Case 1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td width=10%>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
               </td>
               <td width=90%>Test Case 2</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
   ```
4. Add click event to the chckHead class. [**$('.chckHead').click**]
5. Change .attr() to .prop() when setting the check state. [**.prop('checked', false)**]
6. In the click event, get the 'tab' attribute value and use that to select the correct table and set the checkboxes in that table only. [**$('#' + $(this).attr('tab')).find('.chcktbl')**]

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   //accordion
   $(function () {
       $("#accordion").accordion();
   });

   $('#accordion input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });

   $('.chckHead').click(function () {
           console.log($('#' + $(this).attr('tab')));

       if (this.checked == false) {
           //$('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', false);
           $('#' + $(this).attr('tab')).find('.chcktbl').prop('checked', false);
       } else {
           //$('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
           $('#' + $(this).attr('tab')).find('.chcktbl').prop('checked', true);
       }
   });
   ```

   });

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg5mL/embedded/result/) for working example.

Comment: Thanks for the the help. It works perfect in the fiddle but when I implement it to my JSP project the select all function doesn't work. I get a warning about the tab but then I'm not sure if that's the error.

Comment: Never mind. Works perfectly after removing console.log. Thanks again for the help!